# How to change the style of bullets in pandoc markdown?

Tags: styles, markdown, pandoc

Second level bullets in markdown are "-" when converting to pdf. I would like to change them to some other type of bullets (disc or triangle for example). Is there something I can pass in to the pandoc command line to change this? Or something to change in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are two possibilities, both which would involve passing your markdown through a LaTeX style file like so:

```
pandoc -H format.sty -o foo.pdf bar.md
```

The first uses the Beamer template -- [see this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11168/change-bullet-style-formatting-in-beamer) on changing bullet styles in Beamer.  The second possibility uses the `enumitem` package -- [here's another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48036/how-to-represent-cross-and-tick-in-itemize-bullets) on changing bullet styles in this manner.  So, I imagine your style file could simply contain the the following, for instance:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\bullet$}
\setlist[itemize,2]{label=$\diamond$}
```

When pandoc converts to PDF, it will place this LaTeX formatting information directly above `\begin{document}`.

Comment: You can also add this to the yaml using ````header-includes:```` rather than using a style file